# Storing API Keys / Connection String in private Git Repo

Tags: git, security, github

I'm wokring on a solo project and have added my connection string and a couple of API keys to a private github repo.

I'm thinking it's private so it must be safe but I don't know if this is good practice? Recently, I've created environment variables and keep the config on my local pc instead. However, it's still there in Git history.

Should I be bothered to remove this or am I just being paranoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to ensure that you don't have keys stored in the source code. Whether you are being paranoid is entirely up to you. Like all security matters it comes down to a question of risk which you can measure through the likelihood of someone getting your keys and the impact of someone getting your keys.

Looking first at the likelihood, this would require you to share the repository with someone. Given that it is a private GitHub repo essentially you are looking at three options:
 1. You at a collaborator
 2. You make the repo public
 3. You transfer ownership of the repo

Now considering the impact, what does are the keys for? What can someone with access to the keys do? Is it a financial loss for you i.e. they can query a chargeable service as you. Or a data loss, they can get information that is yours from a service?

Having considered the likelihood and the impact you need to decide are you ok with this? For most people if the likelihood is low and the impact is low then they will be ok with it. If the likelihood is high and the impact is high then they aren't ok with it. The grey area which comes down to individual choice is the middle ground.

As you can see, we (StackOverflow community) cannot tell you if you are being paranoid or you have a real issue. However, I hope the information above will help you to make an informed decision for yourself.

If you do decide that you should do something about this you have two options:

1. Re-write the git history for your repo. By rewriting the git history you can remove the API keys from the history of the repo without losing the other, potentially useful, history from the project.

This will mean that the likelihood of someone getting the keys from your git history drops dramatically.

2. Change the API keys. Most services will offer some way of regenerating the keys. If not, you can contact the service support and tell them there is a risk of your keys being compromised, they should then change them for you.

This will mean that the impact of someone getting the keys is virtually zero.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go through my repo and remove all previous references, in the unlikely event that there is a breach or I share in the future and forget they are there.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: if such keys can be easily found from HTML code, proxy etc. just don't bother.

I am against the idea of securing API keys as a general security guideline. Firstly, let's distinguish "keys" and "secrets":

- Keys: to access certain services from a client;
- Secrets: to access certain services from a service.

Other than that, they are almost the same. Usually, they have limited life span, can be rotated, and are not human-readable. Although secrets should be strictly controlled, other APIs keys are not the case, because clients are not secured environments at all.

To gain access to a server, you need to utilize an exploit, or get admin access from social engineering, and so on. It is not guaranteed to success. But you can always figure out how a client app or webpage works from its binary or code. Further more, what's the point of "securing" a tracking key in another place that can be found on the webpage in plain text? And why would you do the same thing for AWS keys in your app if they can be easily obtained from Charles proxy?